# How to use ref on <component> in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having two independent VUE components and I want to communicate between them.

In the first component, I am using `<component>` and added ref to it.

```
<component ref="dynamicComponent"></component>
```

and in that above dynamic component, there is a method(suppose `dynamicMethod`) and I want to call that method from second component.

So for that, I am using below code:

```
this.$root.$refs.dynamicComponent.dynamicMethod();
```

But I am getting `this.$root.$refs` a blank object. How can I call that method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're trying to access `$refs` only after the component is mounted.
You should be able to access the `$refs` in the mounted hook.

```
mounted: function() {
  console.log(this.$refs);
},
```